# How do I get SwiftUI to dynamically respond to user events?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, mvvm, swiftui

I'm an experienced iOS developer, but new to SwiftUI. I'm trying to create a dynamic interface backed by a data model. The following illustrates what I'm trying to do:

The model object:

```
class Book : Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Book, rhs: Book) -> Bool {
        return lhs.title == rhs.title && lhs.author == rhs.author && lhs.favorite == rhs.favorite
    }

    var title : String
    var author : String
    var favorite : Bool = false

    init(title : String, author: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(title)
        hasher.combine(author)
        hasher.combine(favorite)
    }
}
```

The content view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var library = [
        Book(title: "Lord of The Rings", author: "J.R.R. Tolkien"),
        Book(title: "Harry Potter", author: "J.K. Rowling"),
        Book(title: "Under the Dome", author: "Steven King")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MasterView(books: $library)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Library"))
        }.navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct MasterView: View {
    @Binding var books: [Book]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(books, id: \.self) { book in
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        (book.favorite ?
                            Image(systemName: "heart.fill") :
                            Image(systemName: "heart"))
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    }).onTapGesture {
                        book.favorite.toggle()
                    }
                    Text("\(book.title) by \(book.author)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what the result looks like:

[image: Preview]

The appearance is correct. However, I want the `like` buttons to work: I want the tap to update the favorite variable in the model object, and then the buttons themselves should change appropriately.

The first happens, the second doesn't.

What am I doing wrong, and how would I get the dynamic UI updates I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be to conform to ObservableObject protocol, and use @Published property observer so any views that are watching our class notice that the property changed and reload. Like this.

```
class Book : Hashable, ObservableObject {
static func == (lhs: Book, rhs: Book) -> Bool {
    return lhs.title == rhs.title && lhs.author == rhs.author && lhs.favorite == rhs.favorite
}

var title : String
var author : String
@Published var favorite : Bool = false

init(title : String, author: String) {
    self.title = title
    self.author = author
}

func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(title)
    hasher.combine(author)
    hasher.combine(favorite)
}}
```

Than create a separate View for each row

```
struct Row: View {

@ObservedObject var onebook: Book

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            (onebook.favorite ?
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill") :
                Image(systemName: "heart"))
                .imageScale(.large)
        }).onTapGesture {
            self.onebook.favorite.toggle()
        }
        Text("\(onebook.title) by \(onebook.author)")
    }
}}



struct MasterView: View {

@Binding var books: [Book]

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(books, id: \.self) { book in
            Row(onebook: book)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is closer to what I want than the other answer--the point of data model backing is to have a single source directly driving the UI. Apparently, `@Binding` is a counterpart to `@State`, and `@ObservedObject` the counterpart to `@ObservableObject`, but mixing the two doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue of this approach is that

```
@State private var library = ...
```

is an array of references, which are not changed when you change object in `MasterView`, so state of library is not changed, so `ContentView` is not refreshed.

Here are minimum required changes to make this approach work

1) make model duplicatable, by changing initialiser (changes in `class Book`)

```
var title : String
var author : String
var favorite : Bool

init(title : String, author: String, favorite : Bool = false) {
    self.title = title
    self.author = author
    self.favorite = favorite
}
```

2) force changing of book result in changed library (changes in `struct MasterView`)

```
ForEach(books, id: \.self) { book in
    HStack {
        Button(action: {
            // Main idea: modification of book, must modify the library
            // which is bound to state of parent view, which result in refresh
            self.books = self.books.map { $0 != book ? $0 :
              Book(title: book.title, author: book.author, favorite: !book.favorite)}
        }) {
            (book.favorite ?
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill") :
                Image(systemName: "heart"))
            .imageScale(.large)
        }
        Text("\(book.title) by \(book.author)")
    }
}
```

This works. Tested on Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2. (If needed full code from my test env, don't hesitate to notify me).